# Error debug mac ios simulator on visual studio 2017

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, visual-studio-2017

When I run the "remotebuild --secure false" command I get the message:

```
Gabriels-Mac:~ gabriel$ remotebuild
Remote build server listening on [http] port 3000
Please view/edit server configuration at 
/Users/gabriel/.taco_home/RemoteBuild.config. You many need to run 'remotebuild saveconfig' to generate it. You will have to restart the server if you update the server configurations.
```

However visual studio can connect, but when I click to run in the iphone simulator on mac in visual studio the message appears:
`Build failed with error appHelloCordova 1`

And the mac terminal appears:

```
New build request submitted:
/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=6.3.1&cfg=debug
{"content-type":"multipart/form-data;","host":"192.168.230.129:3000","content-length":"2277053","expect":"100-continue","connection":"Keep-Alive"}

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/gabriel/.taco_home/node_modules/taco-remote-multiplexer/latest/package.json'
npm WARN latest No description
npm WARN latest No repository field.
npm WARN latest No README data
npm WARN latest No license field.

Build will be executed under: /Users/gabriel/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/452
Saving build request payload to : /Users/gabriel/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/452
Saved uploaded build to /Users/gabriel/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/452/upload_452.tgz
POST /cordova/build/tasks?command=build&vcordova=6.3.1&cfg=debug 202 15629.523 ms - 629

GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 4.323 ms - 629
Extracted app contents from uploaded build request to /Users/gabriel/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/452/cordovaApp. 

Requesting build.
Taking 452 as current build
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 30.444 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 1.166 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 8.955 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 3.368 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 1.587 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 24.642 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 3.377 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 18.533 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 10.353 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 1.588 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 0.899 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 3.929 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 0.913 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 1.060 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 4.422 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 1.985 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 2.955 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 2.336 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 4.272 ms - 693
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 1.053 ms - 694
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 0.931 ms - 694
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 2.718 ms - 694
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 1.016 ms - 694
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 0.918 ms - 694
Done with current build. Checking for next build in queue.
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452 200 0.846 ms - 698
GET /cordova/build/tasks/452/log 200 36.517 ms - -
```

Anyone have an idea how to solve it?

Comment: Do you have anything else in VS output except poor message `Build failed with error appHelloCordova 1`?

Comment: In visual studio only this message appears